# How to send the last class of a div in an ajax poll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax-polling

I'm having trouble with my ajaxPoll chat system. I'm trying to send the last Id of the chat message's `div` back to `php`, so then the query can only show results that are higher than the last id sent.

All the chat messages are in a `div` called `chat_log`. A message would have a `div` around it with the class of the message's id. It would have the text `message` then the ID of that message, for example: `class="message543"`. Okay so to make it easier to understand, here's a sample bit of HTML, with the structure and in the right order.

```
<div id='chat_log'>
    <div class='message435'></div>
    <div class='message436'></div>
    <div class='message437'></div>
    <div class='message438'></div>
    <div class='message439'></div>
    <div class='message440'></div>
    <div class='message441'></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are 7 messages in the div max. Any messages higher than that are wiped out (all if that works fine, just a little bit of extra information.) Another thing to note, I use the [jquery](http://jquery.com/) library and a jquery plugin found [here](http://pastebin.com/2wD5A2aE), credit to [this](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/simple-ajax-polling-plugin-for-jquery/) blog post. (Information about what the plugin does can be found [there](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/simple-ajax-polling-plugin-for-jquery/).)

---

What I've tried:

```
function ajaxGo() {
    $.ajaxPollSettings.pollingType = "interval";
    $.ajaxPollSettings.interval = 700;
    $.ajaxPollSettings.maxInterval = 1000;
    $.ajaxPollSettings.durationUntilMaxInterval = 2000;

    var httpcount = 1;

    var lastDiv = lastDiv = $('#chat_log').find('div:last-child');
    var lastId = lastDiv[0].className.substring(7);

    $.ajaxPoll({
        url: "place_chat/update.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            where: where,
            'last': lastId
        },
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,

        successCondition: function (result) {
            var responseString = result;

            if (result != '') {
                $(result).appendTo('#chat_log').show();
                lastDiv = lastDiv = $('#chat_log').find('div:last-child');
                lastId = lastDiv[0].className.substring(7);
                console.log(lastId);
                httpcount = httpcount + 1;

                if (!hasFocus && !titleCurrentlyChanging) {
                    changeTitle();
                }

                soundHandle = document.getElementById('soundHandle');
                soundHandle.src = '../Sounds/Message.wav';
                soundHandle.play();
            }
        }

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chat_log').append('<div class="message0">Test</div>');

    setTimeout(ajaxGo, 500);
});
```

---

The code takes off the string 'message', then grabs the number. The code:

```
lastDiv = lastDiv = $('#chat_log').find('div:last-child');
lastId = lastDiv[0].className.substring(7);
console.log(lastId);
```

...works correctly when pasted in the console and outputs the correct, last `div`'s message `id`.

However it does not when ran non-manually (probably because it's not in a function or in a loop or what not), the code for some reason, only sends '`0`', when there are other messages with `id`'s of `1000`+. I've also tried many other things, like `setInterval`'s, Etc. One thing I think may be causing the issue is the variable scope, it's as if when the success `function` of the poll is being called, it won't adjust the `lastId` variable. I'm not entirely sure if this is the case though. If it is the case, I would appreciate support on how to fix the variable scope in order for the code to work correctly.

*On a side note, the php is working successfully, so I need no assistance with that.*

**Important Edit (Make the issue easier to understand):** The code

```
lastDiv = lastDiv = $('#chat_log').find('div:last-child');
lastId = lastDiv[0].className.substring(7);
```

...works fine, it's the surrounding area (the structure) of it is what seems to be the problem. Also `where` is not relevant to this `where` just tells php where the script was sent from. I am aware that there is a div appended on first called `test`, that's to define the first `lastId` as `0`. The **Loop** should handle getting the latest `lastId`, but it doesn't.

**What I have discovered**:
`lastId` is not being edited in the ajaxPoll, it gets the right lastId from the div, but does not edit `lastId`. Which makes it ALMOST definite that it's a scope problem

Comment: What is this `where: where`?  You have made a mistake of some kind there.

Comment: On DOMReady you are appending a div which has a class of `message0` now your last div returns `0`.

Comment: Use a delimiter to grab the value, it's easier: "message_0", then use split("_")

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `lastDiv = lastDiv = $('#chat_log').find('div:last-child');
lastId = lastDiv[0].className.substring(7);`.  undefined didn't you read "when there are other messages with id's of 1000+." ?

Comment: @LeviMorrison that's not relevant to this situation, that just tells php where it's been sent from.

Comment: why not `$('#chat_log > div:last-child').prop('class')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is `ajaxPoll`. You create the data to be sent once and it is not re-evaluated on each poll.

Another problem is that `lastId` is local to the `ajaxGo` function.  Move it outside.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/bLbTH/) that uses `jQuery.ajax` and `setInterval`:

```
var lastId = 0;

function ajaxGo() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/html/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'last': lastId,
            html: '<div class="message' + (parseInt(lastId) + 1) + '">' + (parseInt(lastId) + 1) + '</div>'
        },
        dataType: "html",

        success: function(result) {

            if (result) {
                $(result).appendTo('#chat_log').show();
                lastDiv = $('#chat_log').find('div:last-child');
                lastId = lastDiv[0].className.substring(7);
                console.log(lastId);

/*                if (!hasFocus && !titleCurrentlyChanging) {
                    changeTitle();
                }

                soundHandle = document.getElementById('soundHandle');
                soundHandle.src = '../Sounds/Message.wav';
                soundHandle.play();*/
            }
        }

    });
}

var timer = setInterval(ajaxGo, 1000);​
```

Some code that was not relevant to your question was commented out or omitted.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a scope problem, it will probably be fixed by putting

```
var lastId = -1;
```

at the top of your code, then replacing `var lastId = ...` with `lastId = ...`.